# Print to eps on Win produces Unix line endings (Bug?)

Tags: matlab, postscript, carriage-return, eps, linefeed

On Win7 64b with R2014b, printing a figure to .eps produces Unix line endings (LF or \n). Is this expected or a **bug**?

Also, does it depend on Matlab version?

You can test with:

```
% Plot and export to .eps
plot(1:10)
print(gcf,'test','-depsc')
fid = fopen('test.eps');

% Check if Unix LF only
line = fgets(fid);
if all(line(end-1:end) == sprintf('\r\n'))
    disp('CRLF')
elseif line(end) == sprintf('\n')
    disp('LF only!')
end

% Clean up
fclose(fid);
delete('test.eps')
```

## Edit

Why it matters to me? I am exporting figures to .eps and compiling them with a Miktex 2.9 distribution through epstopdf. However, I get a blank figure and the problem is explained here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208179/epstopdf-error-undefined-in-uagelevel

Now, I was wondering why I never had this issue before. It seems from Louis's answer, it was introduced with the new release and Unix like line endings in the .eps

Comment: Anyone with R2014a or R2013b/a that could post the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off: according to the [EPS format specification](http://www.adobe.com/products/postscript/pdfs/PLRM.pdf) (large file obtained from [here](http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/ps/index_specs.html)):

- Page 26:

  > The characters carriage return (CR) and line feed (LF) are also called newline
  > characters. The combination of a carriage return followed immediately by a line
  > feed is treated as one newline.
- Page 74:

  > The PostScript language scanner and the readline operator recognize all three external
  > forms of end-of-line (EOL)—CR alone, LF alone, and the CR-LF pair—
  > and treat them uniformly, translating them as described below.

So *both forms could actually be used*.

---

I think your test is wrong. You separate lines with `textscan` according to `'\n'`; but that doesn't exclude `'\r\n'` (you will split lines according to `'\n'`, and `'\r'` will remain as the last character of each line).

I suggest you test this way:

```
fid = fopen('test.eps');
s = fread(fid); %// read whole file as a vector of ASCII codes
LF = find(a==10); %// find locations of LF
CR = find(a==13); %// find locations of CR
if all(ismember(LF-1,CR)) %// test if every LF is preceded by a CR
    disp('Every LF is preceded by a CR')
end
```

On my Windows system (Matlab 2010b, Windows Vista 32 bits) it turns out that indeed *every LF is preceded by a CR*, so *Windows-like line endings are used*.

Comment: I changed the test a bit before you posted :). Also, comments from page 74 is equal to page 26? I will edit my original post to elaborate on how it matters.

Comment: Oops. Corrected! I've seen your edit. All I can say is that my Matlab version does produce CR-LF. Good luck!

Comment: Probably unrelated, but have you tried `ps2pdf -dEPSCrop test5-reference.eps test5-reference.pdf`?

Comment: Thanks, haven't tried yet, but was keeping it on the table.

Comment: TMW confirmed it was a change in behaviour in R2014b and while it is not a bug, as you already correctly pointed out, they might revert back.